# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethers.js, ethereumjs, nextjs

Hello Everyone Here is my next js code actually I try to fetch the event data from smart contract but when I mapping the data this error is occur `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`Can anyone help me to fix this error.

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import campaignFactory from '../../artifacts/contracts/campaign.sol/campaignFactory.json';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
const Home = ({AllData}) => {
  const [filter,setFilter]=useState(AllData);
  useEffect(()=>{
    filter.map((e)=>{

      console.log(e.title);
    })
  },[]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>setFilter(AllData)}></button>
      </div>
  )
}


export async function getStaticProps() {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RPC_URL
  );

  const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ADDRESS,
    campaignFactory.abi,
    provider
  );

  const getAllCampaigns = contract.filters.campaignCreated();
  const AllCampaigns = await contract.queryFilter(getAllCampaigns);
  const AllData = AllCampaigns.map((e) => {
    return {
      title: e.args.title,
      image: e.args.imgUrl,
    }
  });
  return {
    props: {
      AllData,
    },
    revalidate: 10
  }

}
export default Home
```

Comment: Hey can you give me more information, which part is not working?

Comment: ```filter.map((e)=>{

      console.log(e.title);
```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: map will work only on arrays, check whether filter is any array.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your state with setFilter at the press of the button "onClick()" but you are mapping the state as soon as the components are rendered with useEffect.
See [useEffect documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect) for more information.

You can try to create a new function that sets your state and then maps it, and call that in the onClick().

Answer (score 0):

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import campaignFactory from '../../artifacts/contracts/campaign.sol/campaignFactory.json';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
const Home = ({AllData}) => {
  const [filter,setFilter]=useState([]);

const getAllData = () => {
  setFilter(AllData);
}

const showAllCampaigns = () => (
  filter.map((item)=>console.log(item))
)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>setFilter(AllData)}></button>
      {filter.length > 0 ? showAllCampaigns: null}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for your cooperation I also did the same but its also not working

Comment: Check whether filter is any array, map will work only for arrays.